# Returning string to Ajax from PHP

Tags: php, ajax

I have an Ajax script that relays form information to PHP upon user submission. The data is inserted into the table and then returns a string back to Ajax. For some reason, instead of getting the string I am getting the full HTML code of the page. How do I go about getting the string instead of the HTML code?

**HTML**

```
  <form id='orderForm' action='' method='post'>

                        <h2>Choose your pizza size</h2><hr>
                            <select name='size'>
                            <option value='' disabled selected>Choose a size</option>
                            <option value='small'>Small</option>
                            <option value='medium'>Medium</option>
                            <option value='large'>Large</option></select>

                            <h2>Choose your toppings</h2><hr><label><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='beef'>Beef</label>
                            <label><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='pepperoni'>Pepperoni</label>
                            <label><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='chicken'>Chicken</label>
                            <label><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='sausage'>Sausage</label>


                 <h2>Enter your details</h2><hr><input type='text' name='name' placeholder='Full Name'>
                        <input type='email' name='email' placeholder='Email'>
                        <input type='text' name='phone' placeholder='Phone number'>


                    <input type='text' name='address' placeholder='Address'>
                        <input id='zip' type='text' name='zip' placeholder='Zip Code'>
                        <p id='message'></p>



                      <input id='submitBtn' type='submit' name='submitBtn' value='Place Order'>
                        </form>
```

**AJAX**

```
$.ajax({
             type: 'post',
             url: 'validation.php',
             data: $("#orderForm").serialize(),
             datatype: "html",
             success: function(data){
                  window.location = data;
             }
       })
```

**PHP**

```
if (isset($_POST["email"])){

$orderId = time() + mt_rand(1,10);

$toppings = implode(', ', $_POST['check_list']);
$result = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO orders (order_id, type, pizza_type, size, toppings, name, address, email, number) VALUES (?, ?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");

$result->bind_param("sssssssss", $orderId, $_GET['type'], $_GET['order'], $_POST['size'], $toppings, $_POST['name'], $_POST['address'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['phone']);

$result->execute();
$db->close();

echo "?success=true&orderid=' . $orderId . '&toppings=' . $toppings";
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use json?

Comment: @AndrewLarsen As in `json_encode($string)`? I've tried that, but it still does not work for some reason. With json_encode, I don't get anything returned back

Comment: Tried with `datatype: "json",` ?

Comment: does changing `datatype:text` make a difference?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Yes they behave different, when doing a request you get different responses.

Comment: @AndrewLarsen For some reason the HTML code is still being returned

Comment: the problem is not `dataType`, is how you access the server or the `PHP` code is failing, I'm running the same code on my side and it's working.

Comment: @julekgwa Are you running the PHP code within the same file or different file?

Comment: different files

Comment: What about the form itself? are you sure you're not reloading the page when you submit he form? (aka preventDefault)

Comment: Paste the html form

Comment: @LouisLoudogTrottier Yes, the page does not reload. I have tried console.log and the html is returned

Comment: @julekgwa I have included the html form in the question

Comment: what are you using `PDO` or `mysqli`?

Comment: @julekgwa mysqli

Comment: @user2896120 where does `$_GET['type']` and `$_GET['order']` come from?

Comment: @julekgwa It comes from the query strings in the browser. Essentially, it is a continuation of another form.

Comment: lets continue this [here in discussion](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143058/discussion-between-user2896120-and-julekgwa)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi I don't how you get `$_GET['type']` and `$_GET['order']`

```
if (isset($_POST["email"])){

    $orderId = time() + mt_rand(1,10);

    $toppings = trim(implode(',', $_POST['check_list']));
    $type = $_POST['type'];
    $order = $_POST['order'];
    $result = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO orders (order_id, type, pizza_type, size, toppings, name, address, email, number) VALUES (?, ?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");

    $result->bind_param("issssssss", $orderId, $type, $order, $_POST['size'], $toppings, $_POST['name'], $_POST['address'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['phone']);
    try {
        $result->execute();
    }catch (Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
    $db->close();
    echo "?success=true&orderid=" . $orderId . "&toppings=" . $toppings;
}
```

form page

```
<head>
    <link href='index.css?<?php echo time(); ?>' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class='container'>
    <div class='startContainer'>
        <?php
        if (!isset($_GET['type'])) {
            if (!isset($_GET['success'])) {
                echo "<img src='order_bg'>
                        <a href='?type=delivery'><div class='orderOptions'>
                            <i class='material-icons'>directions_car</i>                            
                            Delivery
                        </div></a>

                        <a href='?type=carryout'><div class='orderOptions'>
                            <i class='material-icons''>store</i>
                            Carry out
                        </div></a>
                    </div>";
            } else {
                echo "<h1>Success!</h1><p>Your order id is: " . $_GET['orderid'] . "</p><br>
                    <p>Toppings: " . $_GET['toppings'] . "</p>
                    <h1>Your pizza will be ready in:</h1>
                    <h2 id='counter' style='text-align: center'></h2>";
            }
        } else {
            if (!isset($_GET['order'])) {
                echo "<img src='make_pizza'> &nbsp<h2>Choose your pizza.</h1>
                    <a href='?type=$_GET[type]&order=custom'><div class='pizzaType'>
                        <img src='custom_pizza'>
                        <i class='material-icons'>apps</i>
                        Custom made
                    </div></a>
                    <a href='?type=$_GET[type]&order=grandma'><div class='pizzaType'>
                        <img src='grandma_pizza'>
                        <i class='material-icons'>local_pizza</i>
                        Grandma's Pizza
                    </div></a>";
            } else {
                echo "<img src='order_pizza'>

                    <form id='orderForm' action='' method='post'>";

                if ($_GET['order'] == 'custom') {
                    echo "<h2>Choose your pizza size</h2><hr>
                            <select name='size'>
                            <option value='' disabled selected>Choose a size</option>
                            <option value='small'>Small</option>
                            <option value='medium'>Medium</option>
                            <option value='large'>Large</option></select>

                            <h2>Choose your toppings</h2><hr><label><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='beef'>Beef</label>
                            <label><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='pepperoni'>Pepperoni</label>
                            <label><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='chicken'>Chicken</label>
                            <label><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='sausage'>Sausage</label>";
                }

                echo "<h2>Enter your details</h2><hr><input type='text' name='name' placeholder='Full Name'>
                        <input type='email' name='email' placeholder='Email'>
                        <input type='text' name='phone' placeholder='Phone number'>
                        <input name='type' hidden value='" . $_GET['type'] . "' type='text'> 
<input type='text' name='order' hidden value='" . $_GET['order'] . "'>";

                if ($_GET['type'] == 'delivery') {
                    echo "<input type='text' name='address' placeholder='Address'>
                        <input id='zip' type='text' name='zip' placeholder='Zip Code'>
                        <p id='message'></p>";
                }


                echo "<input id='submitBtn' type='submit' name='submitBtn' value='Place Order'>
                        </form>";
            }
        }
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    var count = 60,
        timer = setInterval(function () {
            $("#counter").html(count-- + " seconds");
            if (count == 0) {
                $("#counter").html("Order complete!");
                clearInterval(timer);
            }
        }, 1000);

    var zipCodes = ["30060", "30069", "30090", "30065", "30063", "30061", "30006", "30007", "30008", "30081", "30067", "30064", "30082", '30080', "30339", "30068", "30062", "30066", "30152", "30126", "30160", "30156", "30327", "30144", "30106", "30328", "30111", "30127", "30342"];

    $("#zip").on("focus", function () {
        $("#submitBtn").prop("disabled", false);
        $("#submitBtn").removeAttr("style");
        $("#message").text("");
    })

    $('#orderForm').submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();

        var zip = $("#zip").val();
        if (zipCodes.indexOf(zip) == -1) {
            $("#submitBtn").prop("disabled", true);
            $("#submitBtn").css("background-color", "gray");
            $("#message").text("We're sorry, but we do not deliver to the following zip code.");
        }
        else {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: 'file.php', // change this to php file.
                dataType: "text",
                data: $("#orderForm").serialize(),
                success: function (data) {
                   window.location = data;
                }
            })
        }
    })

</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

In js I recommend you to use:

```
ajax.done()
ajax.fail()
ajax.always()
```

Notice the use of:

```
'method'
'dataType'
```

So, in Js would be like:

```
var ajax = $.ajax({
            method: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            url: 'validation.php',
            data: $("#orderForm").serialize()
        });

        ajax.done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            window.location = data;
        });
```

And in PHP:

```
echo json_encode('your string');
```

### EDIT:

I can't comment cause I'm new hier, so I'll attach my new ideas hier.
I just tested again in-depth.

### ***Test 1:***

I've assigned `dataType: 'json'` and `data: $("#testForm").serialize()` in js. I submitted. In php I checked received values. All ok! I echo'ed an uri string using `json_encode($uri)`. I received the uri string in js and applied `window.location = result`. I was successfully redirected!

### ***Test 2***

I've assigned `dataType: 'html'` in js. I submitted. In php I checked received values. All ok! I echo'ed an uri string using `echo $uri`. I received the uri string in js and applied `window.location = result`. I was successfully redirected!

### Proposals:

So, all works here. But, user2896120, I suspect something. So:

- Your bind_param has "sssssssss" as first argument. BUT at least the $orderId is integer. Change to something like

  $result->bind_param("dsss...", $orderId, /*...*/);
- close the connection before echo'ing your resulting string.
- don't print anything before echoing your resulting string. No echo, print_r, var_dump, etc.
- If you receive html code as result, **READ IT**! Is it **REALLY** your page html code? Or some other html code from an "early" printing (e.g before echo'ing your resulting string)?

### New idea:

If you receive the html code of your page, then check to see if you find also your resulting string "?success=true&orderid=..." at the end of the returned html page code.

### Another idea:

**Obs. apropos 'hidden':**

```
<input type="text" name="order" hidden value="<?php echo $_GET['order']; ?>>
```

should be defined like this

```
<input type="hidden" name="order" value="<?php echo $_GET['order']; ?>>
```

**Obs. apropos 'type':**

Don't use 'type' as value in 'name' attribute. Maybe it is seen as a reserved name! Both at client and db part. And it seems that your data inserting exactly at 'type' value breaks.

So, I mean change 'type' hier (change to 'mytype' maybe, for testing):

```
<input name="type" hidden value="<?php echo $_GET['type']; ?>"
```

Comment: And you should add `header('Content-Type: application/json');`at the top of your php script.

Comment: @AndrewLarsen adding that on top of the script redirects me to the HTML code.

Comment: Since ajax is a variable, how would it get executed so that the script runs?

Comment: Sorry @user2896120, my comment was not good (i'm an SO newbie :-). I reedited it, by it wouldn't let me save it anymore. So, my real comment: jqueryAjax() - in my answer $.ajax() call -  performs the asynchronous HTTP request - jQuery.ajax( url [, settings ] ) - and returns a jqXHR object. This object is in my answer the "ajax" variable, used further for referencing the 'success', 'error', 'complete' and other callbacks. The 3 callbacks are deprecated as of jQuery 3.0. The 'done', 'fail' and 'always' callbacks replace them.